# Applying migrations in views.py if form.is_valid() doesn't work

Tags: django, django-views, django-migrations

I'm trying to run migrations if submitted form is valid, but the migrations are not detected after first form submit. However if I submit the valid form once again, the migrations from previous submit are ran normally.

I also tried with request_finished signal, but the behavior is completely the same.

If I implement extra form to run run_migrations view, the migrations are successfully run, however if this extra form is submitted quickly after first form submission the migrations don't run.

I believe that my run_migrations code is somehow ran before completion of POST request.

views.py

```
def factory(request):

    factory_form = FactoryForm(request.POST or None)

    if factory_form.is_valid():

        # Here I change models.py via python file handling

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('factory:run_migrations'))


    context = {
        'factory_form': factory_form
    }

    return render(request, 'factory/factory.html', context)

def run_migrations(request):
    from django.core import management
    management.call_command('makemigrations')
    management.call_command('migrate')

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('factory:factory'))
```

Comment: That really isn't how you use migrations. Why should they only be applied after submitting a form? Migrations must be applied at deploy time.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I'm trying to make an app that would allow the customization of existing models in project.